# How to validate uploaded file with jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using this script in wordpress.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/master/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/master/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $("#subsciptionForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        headshot: {
                            required: true,
                            accept: "jpg,png,jpeg,gif"
                        },
                        actorcv: {
                            required: true,
                            accept: "application/msword, application/pdf"
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        headshot: {
                            required: 'Select an image to upload',
                            accept: 'Only images with type jpg/png/jpeg/gif are allowed'
                        },
                        actorcv: {
                            required: "Select a CV",
                            accept: 'Only doc/docx/pdf files are allowed'
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        //form.submit();
                        var url = '<?php echo SET_SUBSCRIBER; ?>';
                        var datastring = $("form").serialize();
                        alert(datastring); return false;              
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            data: datastring,
                            success: function(data) {
                                //alert(data); return false;
                                form.submit();
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Here is the form field

```
                        <!-- Upload Headshot -->
                    <tr>            
                        <td class="title_cell" width="23%">
                            Upload Headshot :<span class="required">*</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="field_cell">
                            <input type="file" class="required" name="headshot" size="25"> (jpg, gif or png only, with maximum 1MB size)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Upload Actor's CV -->
                    <tr>            
                        <td class="title_cell" width="23%">
                            Upload Actor's CV :<span class="required">*</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="field_cell">
                            <input type="file" class="required" name="actorcv" size="25"> (MS-word or PDF only, with maximum 1MB size)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

It works well with for image file validation but does not validate pdf and doc file. Keep on giving the same message i have defined in message "`Only doc/docx/pdf files are allowed`".
Also i get this in console :

```
TypeError: b.browser is undefined
```

Edited :

The TypeError is gone after Kevin B help in comment but it is still not validating pdf file. Any idea ?

Comment: b.browser is undefined is from using a plugin that hasn't been updated for jquery 1.9

Comment: jquery link is incorrect, it should be `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` --------  `http:` missing

Comment: @MohammadAdil There's nothing wrong with leaving `http:` off.

Comment: @Kevin B So you suggest i should use down version of jquery?

Comment: @atif, that, or include the jQuery migrate plugin.

Comment: @KevinB it is still the same even after including jQuery Migrate plugin. I guess there is something i am missing or my code has some problem

Comment: did the migrate plugin get rid of the b.browser is undefined error? that's all it should have fixed.

Comment: Yes it did remove that error but i am most concern about validating pdf, doc, docx files :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `accept` rule is for validating by mime-type](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#mimetype).

If you're trying to validate by file extension, you'd want to use the `extension` rule.

See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension

```
rules: {
    headshot: {
        required: true,
        extension: "jpg,png,jpeg,gif"
    },
    actorcv: {
        required: true,
        accept: "application/msword, application/pdf"
    }
},
```

Comment: images are validating nicely but word document and pdf file are not validated. I think you should change the "accept" for actorcv. What say?

Comment: @atif,  how to assemble your project is really up to you.  I'm simply explaining the difference between the `accept` and `extension` rules.

Comment: @atif, yes why not try both of your fields with `extension` rules.